# Calling is_single() outside the loop

Tags: plugin-development, conditional-tags

The file required doesn't load on single posts, it doesn't load anywhere! If I removed the `is_single()` function I can get it to work. My question is how I can check if the current page is a post?

I looked at other questions, it looks like I'm calling the function outside the loop but whatever I try in those answers don't work!!

How would you handle this?
Thanks.

```
class Something {

    function my_func() {
        if ( is_single() ) {
            require_once( '/lib/control.php' );
        }
    }
}

$something = new Something();
$something->my_func();
```

Answer (score 1):

At first, you're calling a WordPress function directly inside a new instance of your class which can lead to a null wp_query state which produces a log when calling your code.

To fix this you should move the call to a place somewhere like the `init` hook, like this:

```
class Something() {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action('init', [$this, 'my_func']);
    }
    public function my_func() {
        if ( is_single() ) {
            require_once( '/lib/control.php' );
        }
    }
}

new Something();
```

Your function will be run after the WordPress initialization is ended and before any headers so, the global `$wp_query` instance now knows what's happening.

If the above solution didn't work for you, You can also try these:

1. Move your call inside the `single.php` file of your theme. (easy, messy)
2. Double check if your `single.php` file had been wrapped with a loop.
3. Try to replace `is_single` method with `$wp_query->is_single()` and see what happens. (don't forget to add `global $wp_query` at the first line of your function)